# html5 video slow connection timeout?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Is there a way to "give up" loading a HTML5 video if the client cannot load it "fast enough"?

- By give up I mean stop downloading data and initiate a fallback option.
- Fast enough could vary but as an example: if a video is too choppy that it would take away from the experience.

Comment: you can bind user-init'ed events like pause() and keep track of when playback stops. if it stops three times with no user input, inform the user it's too slow and stop the video.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use HLS.  This enables the client to automatically fall back to lower bitrate video, or even audio-only media in severe network conditions.

- http://www.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/
- http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/hls/